# ZMQ python socket from context catch exception

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, zeromq, uwsgi

I have NGINX server with uWSGI and python with PyZMQ (installed as  sudo pip install pyzmq).

I'm trying create socket from ZMQ context, but always catch exception.

```
import zmq
import os
import sys
from cgi import parse_qs, escape

sys.path.append('/usr/share/nginx/www/application')
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/usr/share/nginx/www/.python-egg'

def application(environ, start_response): 
    ctx = zmq.Context()         

    try: 
        message = 'Everything OK'
        s = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ) 
    except Exception as e: 
        message = "Exception({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror) 
        pass 

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(message)))] 
    start_response('200 OK', response_headers); 
    return [message]
```

It raised exception

```
Exception(14): Bad address
```

If I commented line

```
s = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ)
```

then is everything ok.

I searched on internet, but nobody has same problem.

Please, do you have any idea, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I wrote simple python script, that working and I get the response from recv:

```
import zmq
import os
import sys

print 'Create zeromq instance...'

ctx = zmq.Context()
print 'Create socket ...'

try: 
    s = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ)
except Exception as e: 
    print "Exception({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror) 
    sys.exit()

s.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')
s.send('fTtt;')
message = s.recv()

print message
```

I seems to be a problem with uWSGI run python ZMQ, but why?

Comment: What is the exception raised?

Comment: edit post for raised exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seem's to be at same error than [ZeroMQ + Django & uwsgi issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071125/zeromq-django-uwsgi-issues)

> The problem arise because zmq context create a background thread and this thread is not inherited after fork().

I try NGINX with simple python wsgi and its work.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you intend to use the socket somewhere below the HTTP response?  Because at the moment you're not connecting or binding on anything, which makes the "Bad address" exception fairly strange.  Try creating a minimal example without the cgi, nginx, cache, response stuff, just the ZMQ context creation and the socket creation and see if you raise the same exception.  If so, it appears there's something wonky in your binding or your library.  Make sure everything is installed correctly and all your versions are compatible.

Comment: No, for testing I wasn't connecting or binging on anything. When that error will by fixed, next step will be connect to localhost on port 5555, where listening my daemon. I was editing question with simple ZMQ script, that working fine

Comment: Well, that changes things.  The error then probably has nothing to do with ZMQ at all.  Have you tried running your script without the ZMQ code and, aside from not raising exceptions, confirmed that it's actually running as expected?